# What CMake version can I rely on in current popular Linux distributions?

Tags: distributions, cmake, compatibility

Suppose I'm writing a `CMakeLists.txt` file for a project of mine. I would like to use some newer CMake features... but I don't want to end up requiring a CMake version that's not present in many users' distributions.

So, my questions are:

- What is the latest CMake version which is no later than the default version included with the current version of the GNU/Linux distributions whose share of the user base exceeds 90%, as of July 2019?
- What is the latest CMake version which is no later than the default version included with the Linux distributions (*that is, including older distros*) installed on at least 90% of GNU/Linux users, as of July 2019?

Also - same question for all Un*x OSes and distributions, if you have data about that.

Comment: Pick some conservative distribution (Debian stable, oldest CentOS still maintained) and check there.

Comment: @vonbrand: Why? I already got a decent answer about ~10 distributions.

Comment: so you don't have to check hundreds of distributions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/download/cmake) tells me that the available versions of CMake in the Linux distributions it knows about are as follows:

- Arch Linux: 3.15.2
- CentOS: 2.8.12.2 (CentOS 7 and 6)
- Debian: 3.13.4 (Debian 10), 3.7.2 (Debian 9), 3.0.2 (Debian 8)
- Fedora: 3.14.5 (Fedora 30 and 29)
- Mageia: 3.14.3 (Mageia 7), 3.10.2 (Mageia 6)
- OpenMandriva: 3.14.5 (OpenMandriva 4.0), 3.11.4 (OpenMandriva 3.0)
- openSUSE Leap: 3.10.2 (this is the release-based distribution version of openSUSE)
- openSUSE Tumbleweed: 3.13.4 (this is the rolling release of openSUSE)
- Slackware: 3.5.2 (Slackware 14.2), 2.8.12 (Slackware 14.1), 2.8.8 (Slackware 14.0)
- Ubuntu: 3.13.4 (Ubuntu 19.04), 3.10.2 (Ubuntu 18.04), 3.5.1 (Ubuntu 16.04), 2.8.12/3.5.1 (Ubuntu 14.04; 3.5.1 is available as the `cmake3` package)

In addition to the above, RHEL 8 has 3.11.4; previous versions of RHEL carry the same version as CentOS (as you’d expect). EPEL carries a `cmake3` package providing version 3.13.5 for CentOS and RHEL 7, and version 3.6.1 for CentOS and RHEL 6.

For non-Linux distributions:

- FreeBSD: 3.14.5
- NetBSD: 3.14.5
- OpenBSD: 3.15.2
- macOS (via Homebrew): 3.15.2

The versions above are the latest version available in each release of the given distribution, not necessarily the default version — I expect most users to be comfortable enough keeping their distribution up to date within a given release.

I don’t know what’s needed to cover 90% of the installed base. If you stick to the latest version of all distributions above, then 3.5.2 covers everything apart from CentOS, and 3.10.2 covers everything apart from CentOS and Slackware. The CentOS situation should be temporary anyway, since CentOS 8 is forthcoming, and can be worked around by using EPEL. If you want to include releases which are still in wide use, then you’re down to 2.8.12.2 since CentOS and RHEL have a large installed base (but again, see EPEL), or 3.5.1 if you want to ignore that but still include popular releases of Debian and Ubuntu.

I suspect the most popular distribution on the desktop is Ubuntu, followed perhaps by Fedora (ignoring macOS and ChromeOS); on servers, RHEL, CentOS and other RHEL derivatives, Debian, Ubuntu, and proprietary distributions used by server hosts, in some order. But it’s impossible to get reliable data. (Distrowatch’s popularity figures reflect the popularity of Distrowatch’s pages on each distribution, not the usage of each distribution).

Comment: Is "Tumbleweed" the current version and "Leap" the LTS version of OpenSUSE? Also, arent' the most popular distributions [MX Linux, Manjaro and Mint](http://distrowatch.org/dwres.php?resource=popularity)?

Comment: @einpoklum Distrowatch measures interest from people who are interested in Distrowatch, which is a tiny minority of Linux users. These statistics have nothing to do with usage statistics. Even on desktop, a vast majority of users just use one distribution and don't care about playing with other distributions.

Comment: @Gilles: I wonder where I can get some more valid estimates of the Linux use distribution. Or... actually, come to think of it - the distribution of _developers_ who might actually download and build anything.

Comment: openSUSE Tumbleweed is the rolling release, openSUSE Leap is the release-based distribution. As Gilles mentions, Distrowatch’s figures don’t indicate distribution usage. I suspect the most popular distribution on the desktop is Ubuntu, followed perhaps by Fedora (ignoring macOS and ChromeOS); on servers, RHEL, CentOS and other RHEL derivatives, Debian, Ubuntu, and proprietary distributions used by server hosts, in some order. But it’s impossible to get reliable data.